# AWS IAM groups not adding rights together

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I created two IAM groups, I call them `general` and `lambda-user`.

In `general`:

- Policy: `IAMUserChangePassword`

In `lambda-user`, I added policies:

- `AWSLambdaFullAccess`
- `AmazonS3FullAccess`
- `AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator`
- `AWSCloudFormationFullAccess`

I thought when I added a user to both groups, he should have all 5 rights above.

Then, the user tried to use cli to perform `serverless deploy` that requires **CloudFormation**, but he failed. The console said he did not have **CloudFormation** right.

Until I removed him from `general`, he could perform `serverless deploy` again.

It seems that the rights in different groups are not adding together, but a group may override another group.

Actually, is my concept of group + group correct?

Comment: can you be more specific and post your policies and tell exactly which action you are trying to perform

Comment: hi, I have updated the question to be more specific, thanks for helping

Comment: Yes, if an IAM user is a member of multiple IAM groups then the user has the permissions associated with the union of the policies of the IAM groups.

Comment: @user3836484 If you are saying that _removing_ them from a policy granted them more access, then it sounds like that policy has a `Deny` that is overriding an `Allow`. What is in the `general` policy? Also, could you please provide the exact error message?